# How can I use my PS4 controller in MacOS 12 as a mouse/keyboard alternative?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, monterey, remote-control

I would like to use my PlayStation 4 game controller as a mouse/keyboard alternative in MacOS 12.4

Previously I used [Controlly](https://hugolispector.com/controlly/index.html#support) but the developer says it doesn't work with MacOS Monterey.  They suggested [Enjoyable](https://yukkurigames.com/enjoyable/), but I can't get that to respond at all (despite being paired correctly).

Is there a way to do this?  I want to use it as an alternative to the mouse and keyboard in (for example) Adobe Audition and Premiere (this isn't a question about using it to play games specifically).